# How to validate datetime values with timezone abbreviations against a specific format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a Ruby on Rails application which has several JQuery DataTables that display datetime values which include timezone abbreviations (EST, EDT, PST, PDT, etc.). I want the table sorting to correctly sort these datetime values in the right order. Even though all rows in a table will use the same locale for datetime objects, the actual timezone abbreviation can vary depending on whether or not daylight savings time was in effect at that time (For example, the table may include both '03/05/18 09:32 AM PST' and '05/31/17 09:04 AM PDT').

I've followed the steps outlined here for adding momentjs formats for date sorting: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18
However, the 'z' format token for timezones has been deprecated from momentjs since version 1.6.0: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/
I cannot just hardcode known timezones in formats (such as `$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MM/DD/YY hh:mm A [PST]')` and `$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MM/DD/YY hh:mm A [PDT]')`) because the formats won't match all items in the column within my datatable, so sorting still will not work.

I've brought in moment-timezone.js and was going to update the $.fn.dataTable.moment() function within datetime-moment.js to use `moment.tz(dateTime, format, useStrict, timezone).isValid()?` instead of `moment(dateTime, format, locale, useStrict).isValid()?` so that I could pass in a format containing a 'z' token, but the moment.tz().isValid() method doesn't behave as I expect it to.

When I try to validate dateTime values with a timezone abbreviation against a format containing the z token, isValid() returns false.

`moment.tz('06/19/19 01:53 PM PDT','MM/DD/YY hh:mm A z',true, 'America/Los_Angeles').isValid()`

This is the exact dateTime string returned to me when I just get back a moment using that format. Example:
`moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm A z');` returns `06/19/19 01:53 PM PDT`

The moment.tz().isValid() function works just fine if I drop the zone abbreviation, and it even returns true when I use the offset instead of the timezone abbreviation:
`moment.tz('06/19/19 01:53 PM -0700','MM/DD/YY hh:mm A Z',true, 'America/Los_Angeles').isValid()`

I'd prefer to keep the timezone abbreviations in my datetime values since it's more convenient for users than UTC offsets. Does anyone have ideas as to why moment.tz().isValid() doesn't seem to work as expected with a timezone abbreviation? Or any alternate suggestions for sorting jquery datatables that contain datetime values with different timezone abbreviations?
I'd even consider converting all of the datetime values to one abbreviated timezone depending on the user's local timezone, but the Ruby Time.in_time_zone() method doesn't take in all timezone abbreviations (for example, passing in 'EST' will correctly display all datetime values in EST, adjusting all EDT times by one hour. But 'PST' is not an accepted value here. Passing in 'America/Los_Angeles' will result in datetime values that could either end in PST or PDT, which brings me back to the issue of sorting them).